# HTTP Webserver with FCGI written in Python?

Tags: python, http, webserver

For a project i need a python webserver (can use C modules if necessary). 
The basic http server from the runtime is way to simple - at least i need FCGI compatibility for some legacy modules.

Is there any other standalone server which is not totally connected to a certain framework like the Zope Webserver?

Performance is not really important.

Answer (score 1):

You can look into following along with twisted mentioned below, which also has fastcgi support.

- http://trac.saddi.com/flup
- http://fcgi-python.sourceforge.net/
- http://webpy.org/cookbook/fastcgi-lighttpd
- http://www.vitohuang.info/blog/2009/06/12/lighty-with-web-py-via-fastcgi/

Comment: This are all adapters for webservers but the highest priority is the webserver itself being in python because i need to hack the webserver, all with experimental stuff which is to complicated for writting a lightppd/apache module.

Answer (score 0):

[Twisted](http://twistedmatrix.com/) can do it [supposedly](http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/browser/trunk/twisted/web2/channel/fastcgi.py).